# What would be the best case scenario for a standard selection sort algorhitm?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, selection-sort

Would the elements be sorted in ascending order or descending order?

Would this be the same for insertion sort?

Comment: Just to check, you're asking for the best-case behavior? Usually I think of the worst-case as the most important one, since that's the one that provides some sort of guarantee.

Comment: When you say "Would the elements be sorted in ascending order or descending order?", are you asking what effect that has on the time complexity, or what a typical library implementation would do by default?

Answer (score 1):

For selection sort, the best case is items already in order. However, that doesn't really improve the running time appreciably. Selection sort has no early-out condition; you have to check every item regardless of whether the list is already in order. It will always do (n^2 - n)/2 comparisons. The only thing having a pre-sorted list does is eliminate the need for n "swap" operations.

For insertion sort, the best case also is a pre-sorted list. In that case, insertion sort runs in O(n). Descending order is the absolute worst case for insertion sort.